Firefox won't open new window when Zoom is running
I'm experiencing an issue with Firefox (installed on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS through Snap Store). When I right-click on the Firefox icon in the dock, I can choose to Open a New Window, and it works normally. However, when I'm in a Zoom meeting (I installed Zoom using the official .deb from the Zoom site) Firefox will not open a new window this way. I suspect I should examine the logs to troubleshoot this, but I don't know where to look. Any help is appreciated :)

How do you start the Zoom, from a link in Firefox or directly from desktop? Does it matter either way? Edit your question and add these information.

I'm right-clicking the icon in the dock
